# SQL Server Multicasting - Will it improve performance?

Tags: sql-server

Apologies in advance for the vagueness of this question. We're having a new product installed and it's performing really badly.

I don't have access to any diagnostics - for this example, let's imagine I'm just a normal end user.

We have been told that enabling multicasting will help with performance. We're seeing a lot of 0x80131904 and 0x80004005 about timeouts and server not responding.

My vague question is whether multicasting would help performance considering we aren't writing to any CSVs or other endpoints. The DB is interacting with a web app and a desktop app.

[image]

Thanks,

JJ

Answer (score 4):

> Apologies in advance for the vagueness of this question.

It just means you'll get a vague answer which may or may not help.

> We have been told that enabling multicasting will help with performance. We're seeing a lot of 0x80131904 and 0x80004005 about timeouts and server not responding.

`0x80131904` is a generic `SqlClientException` and `0x80004005` is a generic windows error. Given that, I can't tell you how enabling a network option may or may not help with two extremely generic errors.

I'd look into the root of these errors and trace it back, there is nothing currently to say that either of them are (or aren't) leading to a performance issue. Please update the question with actual specifics, otherwise you won't get a more specific and helpful answer.

> Execution time Expired

It seems that there is a specified command timeout for the session. By default, using the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace it'll be a 30 second timeout (Thanks, David!). If you don't want one, specify it in the code. If you do want it to error out if it takes longer than the specified time then setting a network property won't help in the query execution. The server will need to be looked over and the queries tuned or refactored along with database objects.